# Derivation of conditional expectation and variance of the AR(1) process

Tags: variance, autoregressive, conditional-expectation

I have a question regarding the **AR(1)** process.
I want to derive the conditional expectation $E(X_{(t)}| X_{(0)})$ and the variance $\operatorname{Var}(X_{(t)}|X_{(0)})$ of the **AR(1)** process: $$X(t)=aX(t-1)+Z(t)$$
Where $Z(t)$ is i.i.d. normally distributed with standard deviation $b$. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Have you looked at related questions on this site? There might be quite a few relevant ones.